# How does the "in" and "not in" statement work in python

Tags: python

I studied predominantly in C and spent a lot of time understanding its implementation under the hood. But I've recently begun learning python. So there are a lot of quirks here different from C.

How does the 'in' statement work in python?

```
if x in array:
   #the usage of an in statement produces a boolean
for x in array:
   #the usage of an in statement produces an iterable
```

Also as a side question. 'Not' can be placed in front of a boolean expression, similar to '!' in C or it can be placed in front of the 'in' statement in python. How is this possible?

```
if not x == 5:
   #makes sense because 'x == 5' evaluates to a boolean
if x not in array:
   #the statement 'in array' is not a boolean
   #shouldn't it be 'if not x in array'
```

How are both of these possible? Shouldn't there be a consistency in how they are evaluated? Right now, I believe that it's because Python is an interpreted language, the interpreter can just do different things based on the surrounding syntax.

An explanation or link to an explanation would be super helpful, I've been unable to find anything addressing this.

Comment: `for <target> in <iterable>` does not have much in common with `<expr> in <expr>` other than that both syntaxes use the letters `i` and `n` in the same order.

Comment: `not x in array` works too, but `not in` is more readable. `in` and `not in` are both operators. As Martijn Pieters said, `for … in` is unrelated and `in` is not an operator there; instead, it’s part of the `for` syntax. This has nothing to do with Python being an interpreted language.

Comment: If you've studied C extensively, you should know a thing or two about the compiler and lexical analysis?
Well, the two types of statements are quite different in that sense... They are simply compiled in an entirely different fashion..

Comment: my question is more about how python can handle both, not which way is better

Comment: Its the same in any language. Certain keywords have multiple uses and the compiler knows how to handle them by context. Take the `extern` keyword in `C`.

Comment: @JohnDoe - Consider the C keyword `const` which can be placed in multiple locations changing semantics: `const char *` vs `char const *` vs `const char const *` - It's handled in much the same way - the lexical analysis by the compiler knows how do deal with the same character string when it's encountered in different locations and orders - it's all a question of the parse-tree being created.

Comment: So you’re wondering how the Python distinguishes the operator `not` from the operator `not in`? `x`, as an expression, can only be followed by an operator and not by another expression (`x True` doesn’t make sense, so `x not` can only begin `x not in` and never `x not y`).

Comment: Here is a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification) to the 'explanation'. In the end, python's grammar is arbitrary, it only needs to be learned :) You can search the string 'in' in the linked page (with the quotes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are confusing two *totally unrelated* pieces of syntax.

One is a *statement*, see the [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) documentation. The `in` is part of the fixed grammar:

```
for_stmt ::=  “for” target_list “in” expression_list “:” suite
              [“else” “:” suite]
```

The moment you use `for` to start a line, the `in` part is required, just as the `:` is required. And don't confuse Python's `for` with a C `for` loop; Python's is a [*For Each* construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach). As such it doesn't 'produce' an iterable, it requires an iterable as input.

The other is a [*membership test operation*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations), and operators are a type of *expression*:

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for membership.

It is meant to apply to containers (not just iterables).

Both are leaning heavily on Python's OO nature, something C can't do. If you want to find equivalents in other languages, look at concepts in C++, Java or C#, not at C.

`for <expr> in <iterable>` takes an [*iterable object*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), something that can produce elements, one after another. C++ has an [equivalent concept](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/), in Java there are parallels in [iterators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html).

`<expr> [not] in <expr>` only requires that the right-hand expression result supports membership testing, but Python will fall back to iteration if no explicit hooks are available for a membership test. The `not` in `not in` simply inverts the result of the `in` operation.

C++ and Java have no standard abstraction for this, different container types each implement their own spelling (in C++ most call it `find`, e.g. [`set::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/) or [`map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), while Java usually picks `contains` variations, giving you [`Set.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), and [`Map.containsKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-)).

Answer (score 3):

The `for x in array:` is not much different from the [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) introduced in c++11. The syntax in c++ is also quite similar:

```
int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int n : a) // the initializer may be an array
    std::cout << n << ' ';
```

The statements `if x in a:` and `for x in a:` do not have much to do with each other, they simply feature the same word `in`, but it has different meaning.

You could easily imagine how one would implement a feature similar to `if x in a:` in c++ - for instance use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). An alternative is to iterate over the container and compare each element to `x`. There can be specific overloads for certain types of containers to make this more performant of course, but important thing is that it *can* be implemented.